# jquery simplemodal redirect to parent page after POST

Tags: jquery, post, simplemodal

I am using the most excellent SimpleModal jQuery plugin (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

I have a simple modal opening from my Index page which displays a form the user must fill out for a particular item.  Upon successfully submitting the form, the modal window reloads the Index() - which means I have an Index() inside my modal, as well as in my parent view.

Is there a way I can refocus the page to reload my parent Index instead of reloading inside of the modal window?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with this:

In the modal:
...

```
document.forms[0].target = window.parent.name;
document.forms[0].submit();
```

In the parent view:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        window.name = "alumnoIncidencias";
});
```

I hope this can help you!